# How to fix alignment problem in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am using xlsxwriter to create Excel sheets using Python. Everything works fine. 
I need to change for all the rows the row height to 23 and the first line of the code below did it correctly.
I also need to vertically align to the center the text in all the rows and could not make it work. Any suggestion how to make it right. I am using Python 3.6.

```
worksheet.set_default_row(23) # Set the row height for all the rows
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_align('vcenter')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to do this, and the way that Excel does it behind the scenes, is to set the row height with `worksheet.set_default_row()` and the formatting with `worksheet.set_column()`.

Here is an example:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Set the default height of all the rows, efficiently.
worksheet.set_default_row(23)

# Format all the columns.
my_format = workbook.add_format()
my_format.set_align('vcenter')

worksheet.set_column('A:XFD', None, my_format)

workbook.close()
```

Note, any cell specific formatting added via the `write()` methods will overwrite the column format. Any data written without formats will pick up the column format.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion is indeed what I was looking for. However I need also to make the first row bold.
    worksheet.write("A1", "Date", bold).
Now, as you said, it overrides the the alignment. How we solve this problem.

Comment: No, I meant you need create a new format that has both bold and center alignment.

Comment: I created the new format and it works Great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_align),you can add format to the cell and apply formats when write the excel file

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_align('vcenter')
worksheet.write(<some params>, cell_format)
```

please refer documentation for more details

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and correct reply. What you suggested works. The only issue is that I have to add the 'cell_format' to each instruction when I write to the worksheet. Is there a simpler way to default all the text in the worksheet to vertical center similar to setting the height of the row. Again, thanks.

Comment: i think you have to pass cell format condition each time you write to a file.if this is solves your issue please mark as accepted answer..happy coding